# nrows not found - Programming in R (intro)

Tags: r

I am trying to get the number of rows of `hw1_data.csv`.

However I have listed that nrows is not found.

Error is as below:

> nrows[(df)]
>   Error: object 'nrows' not found

Comment: It would be `nrow(df)`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Angelly.

`nrow()` is a function not an object.

You can use it this way:

```
nrow(df)
```